# Number of row counts shows after i empty the table and no server supplied when i import the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a strange problem in PostgreSQL. I emptied my table but it still shows the row count as the previous row count and no rows are present. And, when I import the SQL file it shows as **NO SERVER SUPPLIED**? How to overcome this problem?

Count is around 60088 and import through the import option in phppgadmin through a SQL file.

Comment: Unclear. Where is the wrong row count showed? How do you import the file?

Comment: @madth3  count is around 60088 and import through the import option in phppgadmin through a sql file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This count is collected by the server when performing an ANALYZE on the table.
Run `ANALYZE mytable;` and this count should be updated.

This count is not exact like in MySQL because of the transactionnal engine used by PostgreSQL.
More information can be found on the PostgreSQL Wiki : http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting

Answer (score 0):

If you have a aoutvalue id in any SQL server (postgres, mysql, ms sql, ...) and do a DELETE FROM it only removes the table content, not the counter.

Use TRUNCATE instead.